# How to create a grade table data from excel data to html display?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a data table of score, in with it with show score of participant, taking data from excel to html display with an ID input and only show individual participant score with the correct ID. Any Idea for starter, or any site that provide a online form of sure kind.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmZ8O.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is it static data or does it change programatically? For static files I've had success converting to CSV and using [this tool](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm) to output JSON which I use to generate the HTML.